# How to browse compiled SCSS styles in index.html in Angular project?

Tags: angular, sass

I have a **style.scss** file in my project and all global styles are imported in it. by default, this file is included in angular.json, but I want it to be called as a .css file in **index.html**. And be updated with any changes. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the reason you're looking for this approach?